# lpr to print files with different names and directories

Tags: linux, pdf, ubuntu, lpr

I have a script witch use lpr to print the output to a PDF file.
I would like to change the location or even the file name of the saved file.
I read several forums about lpr and did not find anything on how to specify the name and the directory of the printed pdf.
Instead I always get a standard name in my PDF directory.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at cups-pdf, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PDFPrinting . You can configure the output directory and filename with it. The configuration file is /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf.

Comment: helpful but not what I need. There is no clue there on how to make it print on different directory.

Comment: The Out directive in the config file points to the directory where the PDF is saved to.